# can you use django to serve dynamically rendered javascript to the client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I am deciding whether to use rails or django for a smallish web app.

One of the features I love in rails is that you can render .js.erb files, and then serve them to the client as a response, and the browser will execute the script

Is there something equivalent in django? If I change the mime type of a response to text/script will the browser realize it's a script and run it? Also, can I render scripts using the django template language like rails does with erb? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may render js files in Django by treating them as normal 'Django Templates' and using appropriate MIME type in order for browser to detect the files correctly.